# Grape custom validations not triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I have a skeletal rails(4.2.8) on ruby(2.4) app to serve api ,using grape, for a js frontend.I have the following `length.rb` validator at `app/api/killbill/validations/`

```
class Length < Grape::Validations::Base
  def validate_param!(attr_name, params)
    unless params[attr_name].length < @option
      fail Grape::Exceptions::Validation, params: [@scope.full_name(attr_name)], message: "must be at the most #{@option} characters long"
    end
  end
end
```

I have a file called `base.rb` at `app/api/killbill/beta_web`, where I have included validator

```
require "bcrypt"
require_relative '../validations/length'
 module KillBill::BetaWeb
  class Base < Grape::API
  end
 end
```

I have invoked the validator at `app/api/killbill/beta_web/caller.rb`

```
 params do
     requires :name, type: String, allow_blank: true, desc: "Country name",length: 3
 end
 get "countries" do
   query_param = "%#{params[:name]}%"
   @countries = Country.where("name ilike ?", query_param)
 end
```

The api call for this endpoint isn't returning an error when the param length is less than 3.
What is being done wrong here?

Comment: It would be interesting to know the expected behaviour: how do you expect your params to be passed to the endpoint, and examples of requests you're testing. With the information given so far, I can't understand how you're supposed to pass the `name` param to the endpoint. For a GET route, the param should be given in the URL, so it should be declared through `GET "countries/:name"` or using a namespace + `route_param :name`.

Comment: My request would be GET countries?name=Austria